# php mysql + comment system

Tags: php, mysql, comments, dreamweaver

i am creating social media website that have a comment system where the text writen by the user will be posted on the board  and stored in the database  but the problem is that no text is displayed and no text is stored in the database but other fields beside the text are stored so anyone can help me ???

## profile .php

```
<?php  
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once('for members/scripts/global.php'); 

if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$send =(isset($_POST['send']));
$writenCom = (isset($_POST['post']));
if($send && $writenCom){
   echo $writenCom;
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(sender_id, text, comment_date)VALUES('$user_id', '$writenCom', now())")or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

 echo"comment success";


 }


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>
<?php print($_SESSION['first_name']); ?>
<?php print($_SESSION['last_name']); ?>'s profile</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>



<link href="style/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<div class="container center"> 
<div class="postForm">
<form action="<?php echo($_SESSION['first_name']); ?>" method="post">
  <textarea id="post" name="post" rows="5" cols="70"> </textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Post" style="background-color:#DCE5EE; float:right; border:1px solid #666; color:#666; height:73px; width:65px;" />
</form>

</div>


<div class="profilePost">Your Post will go here...

</div>
<!--for posting area -->
<div class="textProfileHeader"><?php echo($_SESSION['first_name']); ?>'s profile</div>


<!--end of posting -->
<div class="profileImage"><img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="250" width="200" alt="<?php echo($_SESSION['first_name']); ?>'s profile" title="="<?php echo($_SESSION['first_name']);?>'s profile /></div>

<div class="profiletextContent">Some Content about  this person profile...</div>

<div class="textProfileHeaderFriends"><?php echo($_SESSION['first_name']); ?>'s Friends</div>

<div class="profileImgFriends"> <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="image with highlight 2/images/new images/imageHover/homeHover.jpg" height="50" width="40" />&nbsp;&nbsp; </div>

<!--
<form id="form" method="post" action="profile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
-->
<!--
<a href="#">edit profile</a><br />
<a href="#">account settings</a><br />
-->
<?php
//}else{
    //header("Location: home.php");
?>
<!--
<a href="#">private message</a><br />
<a href="#">add as friend</a><br />
--> 
<?php
//}
?>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php flush(); ?>
```

Comment: You would make it way more easy to help you if you only showed the relevant parts of your code... Concerning your problem: `$writenCom = (isset($_POST['post']));` assigns a boolean to `$writenCom`. You don't want to know if it's set, you want its value (and you want to sanitize it first): `$writenCom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']);` - But please don't use `mysql_*` - use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: You are calling `mysql_fetch_array()` on an `INSERT` query. That won't ever work.  INSERT queries return true/false, so you would do `if ($query) {// it worked...}`.  You are not escaping your input either, so this is wide open to injections.  At a minimum you _MUST_ call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all of those `$_POST` query inputs.

Comment: create a function that gets user data based on the users id

Comment: And the variable `$writenCom` is the _boolean_ result of an isset() call, not the post value you want.  `$writenCom = isset($_POST['post']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']) : false;`

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski  i am learning now and this is a sample so the injection or the securitu issue i will handle it later but know i need  to know how to post a comment on board and stored in mysql

Comment: ann so that why i keep geting a value of 1 in the text field in the database

Comment: @ PHP NooB if i knew how to do it i would not come here and asking... **I am new for the php /mysql**

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    echo "comment success";
} else {
    echo "insert comment failed";
}
```

`mysql_fetch_array` is for fetching the result set of `select` queries.

Alternatively, you could just test the return value of `mysql_query`, which is either `TRUE` for success or `FALSE` on failure for insert statements

```
if ($query) {
    echo "comment success";
} else {
    echo "insert comment failed";
}
```

Besides that, you should consider switching to either `mysqli` or `PDO`, because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems in your code. First, `$writenCom = (isset($_POST['post']));` sets `$writenCom` to TRUE/FALSE, and this is the value you are trying to insert in DB. Second, `mysql_fetch_array` makes sense only if you execute `SELECT` query. In addition, you should always escape data which comes from user (it's recommended to use `mysqli` or `PDO`, not obsolete `mysql`)

Comment: "it's recommended to use mysqli or PDO, not obsolete mysql" is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @bizzehdee : Didn't you see that it starts with "in addition" ? I outlined problems with existing code, and added a common note about escaping variables